# “门” looks weird on my system default font

Tags: fonts

On my system, the “门” character looks super weird.
I expect it to look like this:

[image: 门 (mén) character that doesn't look weird]

But instead it looks like this:

[image: 门 (mén) character that looks weird]

I'm running Xubuntu 16.10 with the Chinese Language pack but not the Japanese language pack installed. I don't know what font it's displayed in but the second screenshot is from my system default.

Comment: You are using the noto for Japanese font , select other font begin with noto, see which one is for Chinese.

Comment: @user-487 how do I move this question?

Comment: [Can I migrate a question myself?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3478/can-i-migrate-a-question-from-superuser-to-stackoverflow-myself),,,,,,
[move the question](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8480/how-to-move-question-with-no-activity-to-another-se-site/8481#8481)

Comment: @user-487 I can't ask that it be moved other than to chinese.meta.stackexchange.com :\  so I'll just flag it normally

Comment: I think the easiest way is that you ask again on that site.

Comment: For those interested, this shape is a ryakuji in Japanese. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryakuji

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `fc-list :lang=zh-cn` to list all fonts you install. I believe it is the bug in Ubuntu. Your system may use the wrong font to show simplified Chinese.

Take a look at your `/etc/fonts/conf.d/64-language-selector-prefer.conf` file, you may find the following:

```
<alias>
      <family>sans-serif</family>
      <prefer>
         <family>Noto Sans CJK JP</family>
         <family>Noto Sans CJK SC</family>
         <family>Noto Sans CJK TC</family>
      </prefer>
   </alias>
   <alias>
      <family>monospace</family>
      <prefer>
         <family>Noto Sans Mono CJK JP</family>
         <family>Noto Sans Mono CJK SC</family>
         <family>Noto Sans Mono CJK TC</family>
      </prefer>
   </alias>
```

What you need to do is move `JP` item to last. Highly recommand you to install Google [Noto](https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/cjk/).

You can found more [here](http://forum.ubuntu.org.cn/viewtopic.php?t=478915).

Comment: I got this problem on iOS as well, after I changed my phone's language to Japanese. Is there a fix for iOS as well?

Comment: @Sweeper Japanese font show this font error. I think if you change your system's language to Chinese can solve this problem. But if you prefer Japanese, I don't think iOS has an option to choose prefer font.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I never would have found that forum post! This is interesting to me though, seems like a Unicode problem. Almost as if these two characters should not be "unified" under CJK…

Comment: For the future reader: I had this problem in Linux Mint, where the file `/etc/fonts/conf.d/64-language-selector-prefer.conf` does not exist.  I found a solution by creating the file `~/.fonts.conf` ([ref.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73721/how-do-i-change-the-default-chinese-font)), then following the instructions in this answer.