# Input simplified Chinese

Tags: input-language

In my Ubuntu 20.04, I installed Simplified Chinese, and I can switch to Chinese IBus pinyin Chinese input. Most of the time, I think I can get the correct Chinese characters. However, recently I am having problem input this single Chinese words. I intend to input
[image],
but I can only get
[image],
which is not simplified Chinese.

I have tried [Google Pinyin with Fcitx Chinese Input](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Ubuntu-Gaming-Chinese-Input/#:%7E:text=Ubuntu%20Setups,to%20fcitx%20in%20Region%20%26%20Language%20.&text=Click%20Manage%20Installed%20Languages%20.&text=Click%20Install%2FRemove%20Languages%20to,Input%20Sources%20in%20Region%20%26%20Language%20.), but what I get is the same.

My language set up in my Ubuntu is as followings:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A configuration file, /etc/fonts/conf.avail/64-language-selector-prefer.conf, caused this problem. The solution is [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/901488/1559897).